# javax.persistence not included in spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpa

I just created a maven project with this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

but I realized that all these classes are not found:

```
import javax.persistence.*
```

so I have to change the dependency to

```
 <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </dependency>
```

which I find it weird because last update is from `Aug 21, 2017`

there is no spring dependency that includes javax.persistence ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Data JPA itself isn't an implementation of the JPA specification. It is an abstraction built on top of JPA that requires a JPA implementation, typically Hibernate, to function. The JPA implementation provides the `javax.persistence` classes. For this reason, with a dependency on `org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa` alone, the `javax.persistence` classes will not be on the classpath.

If you're using Spring Boot's Data JPA starter (`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`), it has dependencies on both Spring Data JPA and Hibernate. Hibernate then has a dependency on the `javax.persistence` API which makes its classes available to your application's code.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... he's saying he's added the dependency above but he still doesn't have access to the javax.persistence classes.

Comment: @cwittah Andy's reply does answer the question, as the question mentions that the author *replaced* the Spring Data dependency by the javax one, it was not simply added. As mentioned by GameScripting in another reply below, javax is now rightfully replaced by jakarta.

Answer (score 3):

In sprint boot 3, `javax.persistence` has to be replaced with `jakarta.persistence`.